# FiWare WP-OAuth user authentication PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, fiware

I am using KeyRock from FiWare.org. Previously everything seems to work find but now the rest server after user authorization send me the following response. I have looked at the server response and it seems to be a NULL/Empty response. But on the NodeJS the request is processed seamlessly. I am using wp-oauth plugin and have modified it to work with FiWare. I am sending this request via PHP CURL.

```
    {
    "error": {
        "message": "Expecting to find application/json in Content-Type header - the server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. The client is assumed to be in error.",
        "code": 400,
        "title": "Bad Request"
    }
   }
```

Following is the CURL request I am using:

```
$url = URL_TOKEN . $url_params;
$curl = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, CLIENT_ID . ":" . CLIENT_SECRET);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, (get_option('wpoa_http_util_verify_ssl') == 1 ? 1 : 0));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, (get_option('wpoa_http_util_verify_ssl') == 1 ? 2 : 0));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add application/json in Content-Type header?

BR